# calculate difference that is current value minus previous value in timeseries

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an elastic index that are timeseries containing 2 fields that are "timestamp" and "value". the field "value" is a cumulative sum when it is sorted by timestamp. And what i want to do is not to have the cumulative sum when displaying a line chart in Kibana. So, what i want to do is to calculate the difference like this :

```
current value  minus previous value
```

Any idea how to do this in kibana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a visualization (with [TSVB](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tsvb.html)) and use several parent pipelines aggregations, like [serial differencing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-serialdiff-aggregation.html).

Comment: i already tried serial differencing but it seems that it's not working for my use case since i return negative value, it shouldnt be the case

Comment: this is quite strange, as this should be exactly the use case

Comment: it's working in fact, i did something wrong, thanks for your help!